# How to get different background color in alternate columns in a table in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services

How to get different background color in alternate columns in a table in ssrs?
We know how to get diff BG color in Alternate rows but not sure about alternate columns

Answer (score 3):

in tablix add new column at last & set the name of textbox to 'Rownumber' & set value of textbox as expression

```
=RunningValue(Fields!PrimaryColumnName.Value, CountDistinct, "DataSet1")
```

change PrimaryColumnName & dataset1 based on you have in your report

now select tablix row & set expression for background color to

```
=iif(ReportItems!Rownumber.Value Mod 2=1,"#dddddd","White")
```

change color code & name based on requirement .. at last hide newly added column 'Rownumber' from tablix

learn about [RunningValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159136%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Above work for alternate rowcolor

for alternate column color, we have to add some custom code & then use that on every column

```
dim Counter as integer=1
Public function getCounter() as Integer
Counter=Counter+1
return Counter
end function
```

now use/set background expression on each column like

```
=iif(code.getCounter Mod 2=1,"#dddddd","White")
```

Comment: http://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2014/11/ssrs-alternate-change-column-background.html