# Alternating column color for a sorted column group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix with a set of grouped columns (these groups are also dynamic - determined at run time). I'd like each new iteration of the group to alternate background colors. I'm familiar with the solution here: [How to get different background color in alternate columns in a table in ssrs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839844/how-to-get-different-background-color-in-alternate-columns-in-a-table-in-ssrs), but that seems to fail once the groups are sorted - it seems like SSRS iterates through the groups and runs the calculation *before* it then sorts them, which puts the alternating colors now out of order.

I've also seen a solution that uses `DENSE_RANK()` in the SQL statement. Besides the fact that I don't want to change my SQL for what should be a display issue, this also doesn't work because the rows returned are then filtered by the report so again the numbers are thrown off.

This seems like it should be simple functionality, so I'm surprised that it requires such measures to implement. Have I missed something? Has anyone else solved this problem?

Thanks!

In case it helps, here's an example of what the report layout might look like:

```
        Division 1    Division 2    Division 3
        2016  2017    2016  2017    2016  2017

Values  20.5  13.8    12.9  22.6    17.4  18.4
```

I would want the header columns of Division 1 to be one color, Division 2 to be another color, and then Division 3 to be the same color as Division 1.

Comment: You can find the solution here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0a517b0a-2e22-4e0e-ae32-4faddb8cefde/alternate-column-colors-in-sql-2008-matrix?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I've specifically pointed out that this approach does not work in this case. (it's the same solution as the link in my first paragraph).